# Return array from groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I use this script to display dropdown values from AWS Ecr:

```
def profile = "ecr"
def region = "us-east-1"
def cmd_output = "aws ecr describe-repositories --profile $profile --region $region --output yaml".execute()
def awk_cmd_output = cmd_output | ['awk', '/repositoryName:/ {print $2}'].execute()
def repo_names = awk_cmd_output.text.tokenize().reverse()
return repo_names
```

When I run the command into linux shell I get:

```
root@test:~# aws ecr describe-repositories --profile ecr  --region us-east-1
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "repositoryArn": "arn23522033165aws:ecr:us-east-1:73522033165:repository/test",
            "registryId": "23522033165",
            "repositoryName": "test",
            "repositoryUri": "23522033165.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-07T22:30:50+00:00",
            "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE",
            "imageScanningConfiguration": {
                "scanOnPush": false
            },
            "encryptionConfiguration": {
                "encryptionType": "AES256"
            }
        },
        {
            "repositoryArn": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:23522033165:repository/test",
            "registryId": "23522033165",
            "repositoryName": "test-2",
            "repositoryUri": "23522033165.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-09T19:54:04+00:00",
            "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE",
            "imageScanningConfiguration": {
                "scanOnPush": false
            },
            "encryptionConfiguration": {
                "encryptionType": "AES256"
            }
        },
.....
}
```

How I can verify that the script is returning array values?

Comment: where from you are running your script? `return repo_names.getClass()` should return something like ArrayList.

Comment: I run the script inside Jenkins job